# Setting offset of an element with jQuery relative to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

I'm trying to set offset (top and left) of an element relative to parent.

I have a container with position relative and the element that i must position with display absolute. How can i set top and left of the absolute element? Offset set the top and left related to document and i didn't need it.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
this is my code:

```
var styles = {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 10,
        left: 20
    };
$imgScaledCircle.attr('src', pathimg).css(styles).addClass('active');
```

It set all proprerties expect top and left. I didn't understand why.

Comment: Set the `top` and `left` CSS properties.

Comment: I have tried it but it seems not work. I edit my question with my code.

Comment: it should place the code in inine style...  Why it didn't work only for top and left?

Comment: [It works fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/afjgpLq7/)

Comment: I don't know why but if i use a top and left value stored in array:

coord[1]

it didn't apply the styles. If i write:

coord[1] >>> 0

To force the value it work. I write the answer now. That the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31424476/4870013

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way:

```
$(child).each(function () {
  $(this).css({
    top: $(this).parent().offset().top + 5,
    left: $(this).parent().offset().left + 5
  });
});
```

Here `child` is the selector for the child element. You can replace the hardcoded `5` to whatever the position you wanna displace.

Answer (score 1):

A n element with `position:absolute` uses coordinates relative to the first container you find moving up the parent chain that has a position that is either `absolute` or `relative`. Elements with the default `position` attribute (`static`) are not considered during this search.

To place an element inside a container positioned at a given pixel inside the container, the container itself should be declared with `position: relative` leaving its `left` and `top` to default.

```
.container { position: relative; }
.element { position: absolute;
           left: 100px;
           top: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand why my code didn't work. I was placing a value stored in a variable:

`var coord = $that.attr('coords').split(',');
var styles = {
     position: 'absolute',
     top: coord[1],
     left: coord[0]
};`

It didn't work. Maybe because the split method return a string and not a number. If i write this (to force a variable to Number):

`var coord = $that.attr('coords').split(',');
var styles = {
     position: 'absolute',
     top: (coord[1] >>> 0),
     left: (coord[0] >>> 0)
};`

It add the styles correctly. Thanks at all for the help.

Comment: Ah, right - maybe `coord[1] + "px"` would work too. It's probably that jQuery sees that the value is a number, and it adds `"px"` for you.